# Subjunctive clause

Tags: subjunctives

1. I have seen myself being at the lowest.
2. I have seen myself at the lowest.

Which one is correct? Is first one(being at the lowest) a subjunctive clause case?

Comment: I see no subjunctive here.  The first version has a participle modifying *myself*.

Comment: Being at the lowest is not subjunctive? Which sentence is correct then?

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. The first one is not subjunctive though. You could also say "I have seen myself at my lowest"

Comment: Why 1 is wrong? Can you explain?